# QTabWidget tab displays nothing in one of the tabs

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qwidget, qtablewidget

I am trying to create a gui that has a `QTabWidget` with multiple tabs. As a preliminary test I have created one that has two tabs using the same layouts. The first tab (Page 1) is blank but then the second one shows the `QTableView` I created. Both tabs were created the exact same way, yet they perform differently. Anyone know why the first one is blank...?

I noticed that if I comment out the line `int8Window->setLayout(_layout);`. Page 1 shows up with the proper layout and the second tab is blank this time...

Here is the code for the gui:

```
    // Main window and layout
    QWidget* mainWindow = new QWidget;
    QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;

    // Tab widget
    QTabWidget* tabWidget = new QTabWidget;

    // The pages in the tab widget
    QWidget* uInt8Window = new QWidget;
    uInt8Window->setWindowTitle(QString("Page 1"));
    QWidget* int8Window = new QWidget;
    int8Window->setWindowTitle(QString("Page 2"));

    QTableView* tableView = new QTableView;
    QStandardItemModel* model = new QStandardItemModel(5, 5);
    for (int row = 0; row < 5; ++row) {
        model->setItem(row, 0, new QStandardItem("3"));
        model->setItem(row, 1, new QStandardItem(5));
        model->setItem(row, 2, new QStandardItem(2));
        model->setItem(row, 3, new QStandardItem(1));
        model->setItem(row, 4, new QStandardItem(5));
    }

    tableView->setModel(model);

    // Setting the tab page layouts
    _layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    _layout->addWidget(tableView);

    uInt8Window->setLayout(_layout);
    int8Window->setLayout(_layout);

    // Add the pages to the tab widget
    tabWidget->addTab(uInt8Window, "Page 1");
    tabWidget->addTab(int8Window, "Page 2");

    // Add the tab widget to the main layout and show
    mainLayout->addWidget(tabWidget);
    mainWindow->setLayout(mainLayout);
    mainWindow->show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read logs! I'm sure you have a respective warning.

You are assigning same layout to two different widgets. Once layout is assigned to a widget, it is owned by this widget forever.

You need create separate layout for each widget.

I recommend to split this onto couple methods. One is creating a widget for a page (you can use this couple times). Other creating a data model, and other composing tab widget.

Please remember also about memory management! Best approach is to set parent during construction (as parameter of constructor). You have a leak in data model.

Comment: Hmmm, about the memory management comment of yours. I thought Qt manages the memory for you and cleans the memory after the gui window is closed? Right now my constructor has these arguments `testGUI(QWidget *parent = 0)` in the header file. Is this what you mean?

Comment: if you set a parent properly. Qt use tree memory management pattern. Object is automatically deleted if his parent was destroyed. If object doesn't have parent it has to be deleted by other means. In your example widgets and layout have parents set when you add them to layout or assign to widget respectively. Data model here don't have a code which assigns a parent (model can be used by multiple views).

Comment: Ah, so for objects that have no parents I should set them. Ie. `QWidget* mainWindow = new QWidget(parent);`, `QTableView* tableView = new QTableView(parent);` and  `QStandardItemModel* model = new QStandardItemModel(5, 5, parent);`.

Comment: Like I've wrote, when you adding widget to layout or layout to widget parent is assigned automatically. In case of  `model` (which can be shared with many views) you have to assign a parent. Usually it will be your `MainWindow`, which plays a role of a controller.

Comment: One more question, for Qt widgets that are class members of a class that has QWidget as a parent, ie. `testGUI::testGUI(char** argv, QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent), _argv(argv) {}`, do these widgets get destroyed when the gui closes on its own or do I still need to assign a parent? I ask this because the class testGUI has QWidget as its parent, so I would imagine that all its Qt class members would be destroyed along with the testGUI class itself.